# Important algorithm involving random access to a string?

Tags: string, algorithm, character

I am implementing a different string representation where accessing a string in non-sequential manner is very costly. To avoid this I try to implement certain position caches or character blocks so one can jump to certain locations and scan from there.

In order to do so, I need a list of algorithms where scanning a string from right to left or random access of its characters is required, so I have a set of test cases to do some actual benchmarking and to create a model I can use to find a local/global optimum for my efforts.

Basically I know of:

```
String.charAt
String.lastIndexOf
String.endsWith
```

One scenario where one needs right to left access of strings is extracting the file extension and the file name (item) of paths.

For random access i find no algorithm at all unless one has prefix tables and access the string more randomly checking all those positions for longer than prefix strings.

Does anyone know other algorithms with either right to left or random access of string characters is required?

[Update]
The calculation of the hash-code of a String is calculated using every character and accessed from left to right along the value is stored in a local primary variable. So this is not something for random access.

Also the MD5 or CRC algorithm also all process the complete string. So I do not find any random access examples at all.

Comment: from right to left? This is not how hashes are calculated, I think.

Comment: Sure this is an example of not left to right but random. I update the post

Comment: Accessing your string, for example using a hash of some kind, is not an algorithm so much as it is an implementation.  Can you tidy up the wording of your question and let us know exactly what you still need to proceed?

Comment: A hashmap perhaps, so a character inside a string is indexed by its character code.

Comment: Is there any scenario where one might want to index characters inside a string? Inverse index of words inside larger text does not require random access for its usage and building the index is done left to right... . Maybe prefix search to speed up text pattern look-ups?

Comment: Are you using a linked list or similar for your string which makes random access expensive? if so, I don't know how to improve random access,but you can change it to double linked so you can access it from right to left quickly.

Comment: I transform the characters to another format that has variable bit length. I try to save some bits in case it is just ASCII characters and alike. So I have to iterate over the characters in order to find the real position. A offset table needs to be cost effective and therefore I use a cached version that stores some sampled positions of former runs. 

I do not look for solutions but for circumstances the problem arises and random access is used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting algorithm is [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) searching, which involves both skipping forward by a variable number of characters and comparing backwards. If those two operations are not O(1), then KMP searching becomes more attractive, but BM searching is much faster for long search patterns (except in rare cases where the search pattern contains lots of repetitions of its own prefix). For example, BM shines for patterns which must be matched at word-boundaries.

BM can be implemented for certain variable-length encodings. In particular, it works fine with UTF-8 because misaligned false positives are impossible. With a larger class of variable-length encodings, you might still be able to implement a variant of BM which allows forward skips.

There are a number of algorithms which require the ability to reset the string pointer to a previously encountered point; one example is word-wrapping an input to a specific line length. Those won't be impeded by your encoding provided your API allows for saving a copy of an iterator.